# Fast-CSV stream transform async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I am attempting to read a csv line by line, lookup a value in a mongodb and transform the read stream prior to piping it back to a write stream.  I am using the fast-csv library for csv parsing.

When the below snippet is called it proceeds up to the row console.log inside the transform and then hangs.  I do not get any error logging even if i let the process time out.

What principle of async stream structure am I missing?

Or how do I get some error information out of this example?  Try/catch never triggers.

```
    var db = mongojs("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/", ['collection']);
    fs.createReadStream(path)
    .pipe(csv.parse({headers: false}))
    //pipe the parsed input into a csv formatter
    .pipe(csv.format({headers: true}))
    //Using the transform function from the formatting stream
    .transform(function(row, next){
            console.log(row);
            db.collection.find({email: row[0].toString()}, function (err, docs) {
                console.log(docs[0]);
                console.log(err);
                if (!err && docs.length > 0) {
                    next(void 0, {
                        email: docs[0].email,
                        name: docs[0].name
                    });
                } else {
                    next(err)
                }
            });
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("tmp/list.csv"))
    .on("finish", function() {upload();});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform is expecting next() function to proceed to the next row but your code got stuck on *next* function.

Try Below correction,

```
if (!err && docs.length > 0) {
                ***perform your operation here***
                next();
            } else {
                next();
            }
```

PS - Sorry for replying so late